# Where did I go wrong in the following integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> $$I_n=\int _{-1}^{1}|x|\left(1-x+\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac {x^3}{3}+\ldots+\frac {x^{2n}}{2n}\right)dx. $$

This is how I solved:
Let $$I_n=\int _{-1}^{1}|x|\left(1-x+\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac {x^3}{3}+\ldots+\frac {x^{2n}}{2n}\right)dx. \tag{1} $$
Since $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$, so $$I_n=\int _{-1}^{1}|x|\left(1+x+\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {x^3}{3}+\ldots+\frac {x^{2n}}{2n}\right)dx. \tag{2}  $$
Then on adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$I_n=2\int _{-1}^{1}|x|\left(1+\frac {x^2}{2}+\ldots+\frac {x^{2n}}{2n}\right)dx. \tag{3}$$
Now let the inside of integral $(3)$ be $f(x)$, i.e.,  $$f(x)=|x|\left(1+\frac {x^2}{2}+\ldots+\frac {x^{2n}}{2n}\right).$$
As we can see $f(x)=f(-x)$ [an even function]. We can use the property $\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=2\int_0^af(x)dx$. So $$I_n=2 \left(2\int _{0}^{1}x\left(1+\frac {x^2}{2}+\ldots+\frac {x^{2n}}{2n}\right)dx\right) $$
$$\implies I_n=4\int_0^1\left( x+\frac{x^3}{2}+\ldots+\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n}\right)dx.$$
Now on integrating we get $$I_n=4\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{4\cdot 6}+\ldots+\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+2)}\right]$$
$$I_n=4\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{12}+\ldots+\frac{1}{4n}-\frac{1}{4n+4}\right]$$
$$\implies I_n=4\left[\frac34-\frac{1}{4n+4}\right].$$
But my above answer is incorrect according to the author.
***But this is how the author solved and I did not understand what he did:***
$$\because \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=0$$
So $$I_n=2 \left(\int _{0}^{1}x\left(1+\frac {x^2}{2}+\ldots+\frac {x^{2n}}{2n}\right)dx\right)  $$
$$\implies I_n=2\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{4 \cdot 6}+\ldots+\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+2)}\right]$$
$$\implies I_n=2\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{12}+\ldots+\frac{1}{4n}-\frac{1}{4n+4}\right]$$
$$\implies I_n=2\left[\frac34-\frac{1}{4n+4}\right].$$
***This is where I am unable to understand. I got an answer which is two times of the author's answer.

I could not point out any error in my method but at the same time I could not understand what actually the author did at the step where he removed the modulus.***

Comment: The LHS of (3) should be $2I_n$.

Comment: @ Saad, Thanks!